# insertupdate sql mysql and jpa entity

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, entity

I am trying to run an mysql sql statement using the code below;

```
public void createUpdate(Tsaleline entity) {
    //Insert
    String sql = "Insert into tSaleLine (CenterId, ProductId, Price, VATRate) "
            + "Select :centerId, :productId, :price, :vatrate "
            + "where (Select count(*) from tSaleLine where CenterId = :centerId and ProductId = :productId)=0; "
            //Update
            + "Update tSaleLine "
            + "set CenterId = :centerId, "
            + "ProductId = :productId, "
            + "Price = :price, "
            + "VATRate = :vatrate "
            + "where CenterId = :centerId and ProductId = :productId; ";

    Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql);

            q.setParameter("centerId", entity.getCenterId())
            .setParameter("productId", entity.getProductId())
            .setParameter("price", entity.getPrice())
            .setParameter("vatrate", entity.getVATRate())
            .executeUpdate();
}
```

}

but it rises a error :

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only insert if the record does not exist. Afterwards it will update price and vatrate for the specified record.

```
public void createUpdate(Tsaleline entity) {
    //Insert
    String sql = "Insert into tSaleLine (CenterId, ProductId, Price, VATRate) "
            + "Select :centerId, :productId, :price, :vatrate "
            + "where not exists (Select * from tSaleLine where CenterId = :centerId and ProductId = :productId); "
            //Update
            + "Update tSaleLine "
            + "set Price = :price, "
            + "VATRate = :vatrate "
            + "where CenterId = :centerId and ProductId = :productId; ";

    Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql);

            q.setParameter("centerId", entity.getCenterId())
            .setParameter("productId", entity.getProductId())
            .setParameter("price", entity.getPrice())
            .setParameter("vatrate", entity.getVATRate())
            .executeUpdate();
}
```

This is not the ideal solution, because the JPA implementation you are using should be taking care of an INSERT or UPDATE to an entity.

Comment: I am trying to do checking a record with the given "CenterId" and "ProductId" if it is exists given data should be updated if not inserted.

in that case i think i should change the where like "not exists (..."

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your needs. Is there a reason why you don't use your JPA implementation's methods to do this? I.E. Hibernate saveOrUpdate() method.

Comment: well this is a cross reference table with product price information and I don't have the primary key for the all record.

Comment: Nop... I changed the sql it is same.  can you see any syntax error or do you know any workaround about that situation.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your stack trace to see the full error detail?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest Marcelo, I did it kind of lame way.

```
            entity.Tsaleline saleline = sf.findByProductIdCenterId(Integer.parseInt(productIds[i]), Integer.parseInt(centerIds[i]));
            if (saleline != null)
            {
                saleline.setPrice(Float.parseFloat(price[i]));
                saleline.setVATRate(Float.parseFloat(vat[i]));
                sf.edit(saleline);
            }
            else
            {
                saleline = new entity.Tsaleline(Integer.parseInt(productIds[i]), Integer.parseInt(centerIds[i]), Float.parseFloat(price[i]), Float.parseFloat(vat[i]));
                sf.create(saleline);
            }
```